# Add select result to another select and create a json key

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I've created a query which returns me all surveys in `survey` table which are not in `survey_completion` and belong to `user_Id = 1`:

My functional query is :

```
SELECT * 
FROM `survey` 
WHERE id NOT IN (
    SELECT `survey_id`
    FROM `survey_completion` 
    WHERE `user_id` = 1)
```

In result to this query, I want to select every row in table `question` with row `question.survey_id` = `survey.id` and return it as `questionsList` key in the JSON response

I added this to the query but it isn't working :

```
AND (SELECT *
     FROM question
     WHERE question.survey_id = survey.idas) AS questionsList
```

MariaDB returns an error on `AS` prefix and I'm unable to fix this

Does someone know how I can fix this ?

**To give your more details**

What I want as return of the query would be that :

```
id: 1
name: 'test'
questionsList [
  {
    id: 1
    survey_id: 1
    question: 'How are you?'
  }
]
```

Currently my table `survey` has as rows `id, name` and my table `question` has as rows `id, survey_id, question, user_id`

So, I want to append to every questions which has as `survey_id` the same id of `survey`, get this list as a new nested list inside JSON and return with the key name `questionsList`

**EDIT** : Heard about UNION to do that, would this be useful in my case but the two tables have different columns?

Comment: Without seeing the query, there is not much that anyone can do.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Sorry, had to edit the question because StackOverFlow was declining my question, I don't know why

Comment: What are you trying to get? All the questions for user 1's uncompleted surveys?

Comment: @Arth I'm trying to get all the questions for user 1's uncompleted surveys and append them to the result of the query (SELECT * survey) as nested key inside JSON. I'm editting main post to let you see my DB tables' schemas

Comment: Could you edit your post and put the tables structure with some data: `survey`, `survey_completion` and `question`?

Answer (score 0):

Building JSON in a query is a little messy, but I think the following would work.. and return one row per survey

```
   SELECT JSON_OBJECT(
            "id", s.id,
            "name", s.name,
            "questionList", JSON_ARRAYAGG(
              JSON_OBJECT(
                "id", q.id,
                "question", q.question 
              )  
            )
          ) survey_object
     FROM survey s /** surveys **/

     JOIN question q /** with their questions */
       ON q.survey_id = s.id 

LEFT JOIN survey_completion sc /** with their completions by user 1 */ 
       ON sc.survey_id = s.id
      AND sc.user_id = 1

    WHERE sc.survey_id IS NULL /** where there are no completions by user 1 */  

 GROUP BY s.id /** grouped by survey */
```